# AWS-SQS: How to set maxConcurrentConsumers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, message-queue, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

We have a requirement where we need to process 1 message at a time(not is strict order) from start to finish using SQS. Is there anyway we can set maxConcurrentConsumer to 1 in SQS?

I am looking into the documents but could not find this property to set. On the Amazon console, I do not see this property in configure queue menu. At the time of message retrieval we can specific how many messages we want to read in a single poll but since AWS auto scaling feature can create multiple consumers(actually Springboot microservices) we can not rely on it by setting this limit to 1.

P.S. : We can not control message sender, it can send many messages into SQS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a setting that controls the maximum number of concurrent SQS consumers. As you alluded to, it is a common practice to horizontally scale queue consumers based on the size of the queue. If, for whatever reason, your requirement is to have a single queue consumer then you will have to remove or disable the queue consumers from the other microservices so you only have one consumer.

However, I encourage you to reconsider the design for only allowing a single queue consumer as that implementation does not scale.

Comment: I know this is not the best way to design as we are seriously limiting the scaling capacity of our application. The fact is that we are locked-in into a product which is the consumer of these messages & it can not handle multiple threads. It is running into a race condition under heavy load. For short term we need to somehow limit the number of instances of SQS consumers till the product is fixed. I think the only option here as suggested is to manually comment the SQS in application properties file. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried playing with any of the SQS queue's settings, especially the visibility timeout? It might not make any difference based on what exactly is causing the race condition but the visibility timeout controls how long a message is invisible to other consumers. So if you set a larger visibility timeout you could help prevent multiple consumers from getting the same message concurrently. Again, it might not make a bit of difference but wanted to mention it.